# Dynamic dropdown reactjs from back end

Tags: reactjs, dropdown

I have select dropdown in my form

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Organization Type</label>
  <select id = "dropdown" name="org_type" onChange={handleChange} value={values.org_type}  class="form-control">
    <option value="1">kkj</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

so I have created

```
const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  setOptions(["op1","0p2"])
  if (Object.keys(errors).length === 0 && isSubmitting) {
    onSubmitform();
  }
}, [errors]);
```

then

```
<select id = "dropdown" name="org_type" onChange={handleChange} value={values.org_type}  class="form-control">
  { options.map((element, index) => <option key={index}>{element}</option>) }
</select>
```

`onSubmitform` inside `useEffect` is not working.

Comment: use `[errors, options]` in useEffect

Comment: have a form, so and then?